# How to ignore .DS_Store files when using `zip` command to compress files?

Tags: macos, shell, zip

I'm thinking of writing a script which copies all useful files into a temp folder and `zip` the temp folder. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
zip -r archivename.zip archivedirectory -x "*.DS_Store"
```

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/30/how-to-exclude-files-from-a-zip-archive/).

Comment: Note that this won't ignore .DS_Store files in subdirectories. `zip -r archivename.zip archivedirectory -x "**/.DS_Store"` will.